# Ligatures on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, ligature

so I have this wordpress website with ACF (advanced custom fields) that generate text (wysywyg).
I use "Benton Light" font. It displays perfectly on Chrome and IE, but Firefox has problem displaying the *ligatures*.

I tried different solutions as CSS3 :

```
font-feature-settings: "liga=0";
font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;
```

(did not work)

also tried with some [js script](https://code.google.com/p/ligature-js/) without success.
I have read a few articles and post and can't seem to find a good solution on the web.
Anyone ?

thank you for your time

Comment: have you tried -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=0";

Comment: @Andi yes I have. not working either

Comment: Same case here, I'm using Google WebFonts with latin characters (e.g. with ligatures, and ligature characters are shown bolder than normal characters. In Chrome/IE everything renders fine.

Comment: I, unfortunatly, did not solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS-Attribute:

```
letter-spacing: -.1px;
```

This worked for me.